# Docker daemon not starting after adding the -H flag

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm trying to use Docker Swarm, to do that I need to start the Docker daemon with the -H flag on each node using this command:

```
docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -d
```

When doing this on my node (Debian 8, Docker 1.6.0) the command never stops, even if it displays that the daemon has completed initialization.

The complete output:

```
INFO[0000] +job init_networkdriver()                    
INFO[0000] +job serveapi(tcp://0.0.0.0:2375)            
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on tcp (0.0.0.0:2375)     
INFO[0000] /!\ DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting -tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING /!\ 
INFO[0000] -job init_networkdriver() = OK (0)           
WARN[0000] mountpoint for memory not found              
INFO[0000] Loading containers: start.                   
INFO[0000] Loading containers: done.                    
INFO[0000] docker daemon: 1.6.0 4749651; execdriver: native-0.2; graphdriver: aufs 
INFO[0000] +job acceptconnections()                     
INFO[0000] -job acceptconnections() = OK (0)            
INFO[0000] Daemon has completed initialization
```

After this last line nothing happens and I'm not able to write another command.

I also ran the command using `screen` to be able to run a command after the first one but I have a error message when running a Docker command:

```
FATA[0000] Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?
```

This command clearly states that the daemon didn't start correctly. How could I have a Docker daemon that starts and ensures that remote API on Swarm Agents is available over TCP for the Swarm Manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This commands states the **client cannot talk to the docker daemon/engine/server**. According to logs, your server is *running*.

With only the `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`, if you didn't export `DOCKER_HOST=127.0.0.1:2375`, the docker client won't be able to talk to the daemon. You have 2 ways to handle this :

1. Exporting `DOCKER_HOST`

   ```
   # Exporting DOCKER_HOST when you want to talk to it
   $ export DOCKER_HOST=127.0.0.1:2375
   $ docker ps
   ```
2. Or update your server options to also bind to the socket, like this

   ```
   # docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix://var/run/docker.sock -d
   $ docker ps
   ```

Comment: Thanks, after reading your answer I added `-H 0.0.0.0:2375` at the line `DOCKER_OPTS` in `/etc/default/docker` to update the server options.